# If the user has still session, I want to go to log in if none, and to dashboard if it occurs using auto route

Tags: flutter, session, token

I have checker for session token, and I want to put it in the main using future builder, and if it has session token, it will go to dashboard using auto route, and login if it does not have.

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  final AuthServices auth = AuthServices();
  await auth.getToken();

  runApp(
    MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => AssetsServices()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => AuthServices()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => ConsentServices()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => DashboardServices()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => HelpServices()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => JobsService()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => PermissionServices()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => SettingsService()),
      ],
      child: MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  final AppRouter appRouter = AppRouter();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final AuthServices auth = Provider.of<AuthServices>(context);

    return MaterialApp.router(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      routerConfig: appRouter.config(),
      theme: CustomTheme.themeData,
      builder: (context, router) {
        return FutureBuilder(
          future: auth.getToken(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
              return auth.token.isEmpty
                  ? AutoRouter.of(context).push(LoginRoute())
                  : AutoRouter.of(context).push(DashboardRoute());
            } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return Center(
                child: Text("Snapshot: ${snapshot.error}"),
              );
            }
            return const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I don’t know what problem you have. But you should probably do this instead of what you are doing now: return auth.token.isEmpty ? LoginRoute() : DashboardRoute(); You don’t need the AutoRouter.of(context).push here.

Comment: When i try that, Unhandled Exception: AutoRouter operation requested with a context that does not include an AutoRouter.
E/flutter (30865): The context used to retrieve the Router must be that of a widget that is a descendant of an AutoRouter widget.

this error gives me

Comment: Can you post the code which gives the error somewhere?

Comment: E/flutter (30865): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: AutoRouter operation requested with a context that does not include an AutoRouter.
E/flutter (30865): The context used to retrieve the Router must be that of a widget that is a descendant of an AutoRouter widget.
E/flutter (30865): #3      _LoginScreenState.initState.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>

Comment: The code, not the error.

Comment: I just changed the code to LoginRoute() : DashboardRoute(), everything is still the same,

Comment: Which line is the error pointing to? That change didn’t cause the error.